# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$next[0].offsetWidth')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

Pease help me in resolving a yet problem you have seen already. I have spent two days looking and using every suggested method and still failing:
This is my `html` code for the carousal. A class `active` is applied to `carousel-item`.

```
  <div class="block block-bordered-lg pl-0 pt-0 pr-0">
  <div id="carouselExampleCaptions" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see the here is the change I made according to the comments suggested.

```
    <div class="carousel-item"> 
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

This the javascript:

```
 var Carousel = function (element, options) {
    this.$element    = $(element);
    this.$indicators = this.$element.find('.carousel-indicators');
    this.options     = options;
    this.paused      = null;
    this.sliding     = null;
    this.interval    = null;
    this.$active     = null;
    this.$items      = null;

    this.options.keyboard && this.$element.on('keydown.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.keydown, this));

    this.options.pause == 'hover' && !('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) && this.$element
      .on('mouseenter.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.pause, this))
      .on('mouseleave.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.cycle, this));
  }

  Carousel.VERSION  = '3.3.6';

  Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION = 600;

  Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
    interval: 5000,
    pause: 'hover',
    wrap: true,
    keyboard: true
  }

  Carousel.prototype.keydown = function (e) {
    if (/input|textarea/i.test(e.target.tagName)) return;
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37: this.prev(); break;
      case 39: this.next(); break;
      default: return;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  }

  Carousel.prototype.cycle = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = false);

    this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval);

    this.options.interval
      && !this.paused
      && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval))

    return this;
  }

  Carousel.prototype.getItemIndex = function (item) {
    this.$items = item.parent().children('.item');
    return this.$items.index(item || this.$active);
  }

  Carousel.prototype.getItemForDirection = function (direction, active) {
    var activeIndex = this.getItemIndex(active);
    var willWrap = (direction == 'prev' && activeIndex === 0)
                || (direction == 'next' && activeIndex == (this.$items.length - 1));
    if (willWrap && !this.options.wrap) return active;
    var delta = direction == 'prev' ? -1 : 1;
    var itemIndex = (activeIndex + delta) % this.$items.length;
    return this.$items.eq(itemIndex);
  }

  Carousel.prototype.to = function (pos) {
    var that        = this;
    var activeIndex = this.getItemIndex(this.$active = this.$element.find('.item.active'));

    if (pos > (this.$items.length - 1) || pos < 0) return;

    if (this.sliding) return this.$element.one('slid.bs.carousel', function () { that.to(pos); }); // yes, "slid"
    if (activeIndex == pos) return this.pause().cycle();

    return this.slide(pos > activeIndex ? 'next' : 'prev', this.$items.eq(pos));
  }

  Carousel.prototype.pause = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = true);

    if (this.$element.find('.next, .prev').length && $.support.transition) {
      this.$element.trigger($.support.transition.end);
      this.cycle(true);
    }

    this.interval = clearInterval(this.interval);

    return this;
  }

  Carousel.prototype.next = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return;
    return this.slide('next');
  }

  Carousel.prototype.prev = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return;
    return this.slide('prev');
  }

  Carousel.prototype.slide = function (type, next) {
    var $active   = this.$element.find('.item.active');
    var $next     = next || this.getItemForDirection(type, $active);
    var isCycling = this.interval;
    var direction = type == 'next' ? 'left' : 'right';
    var that      = this;

    if ($next.hasClass('active')) return (this.sliding = false);

    var relatedTarget = $next[0];
    var slideEvent = $.Event('slide.bs.carousel', {
      relatedTarget: relatedTarget,
      direction: direction
    })
    this.$element.trigger(slideEvent);
    if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return;

    this.sliding = true;

    isCycling && this.pause();

    if (this.$indicators.length) {
      this.$indicators.find('.active').removeClass('active');
      var $nextIndicator = $(this.$indicators.children()[this.getItemIndex($next)]);
      $nextIndicator && $nextIndicator.addClass('active');
    }

    var slidEvent = $.Event('slid.bs.carousel', { relatedTarget: relatedTarget, direction: direction }); // yes, "slid"
    if ($.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('slide')) {
      $next.addClass(type);
      $next[0].offsetWidth; // force reflow
      $active.addClass(direction);
      $next.addClass(direction);
      $active
        .one('bsTransitionEnd', function () {
          $next.removeClass([type, direction].join(' ')).addClass('active');
          $active.removeClass(['active', direction].join(' '));
          that.sliding = false;
          setTimeout(function () {
            that.$element.trigger(slidEvent);
          }, 0);
        })
        .emulateTransitionEnd(Carousel.TRANSITION_DURATION);
    } else {
      $active.removeClass('active');
      $next.addClass('active');
      this.sliding = false;
      this.$element.trigger(slidEvent);
    }

    isCycling && this.cycle();

    return this;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your method `getItemForDirection`.

**Case:** `wrap=true`, `direction=prev` and `activeIndex=0`:

`(activeIndex + delta) % this.$items.length` will return `-1`.

Please update this logic as mentioned below to fix this issue.

```
(this.$items.length + activeIndex + delta) % this.$items.length
```